# Detect shift key in angular 5

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive

i have an issue . i am trying to detect is shift key is pressed or not.
This what i tried but didn't work with me

html :

```
<input
  type="text" 
  class="form-control" 
  dir="rtl" 
  (input)="shiftkey($event)" 
  #myInput>
```

ts:

```
    @ViewChild('myInput', {
      read: ElementRef
    })
    txt: ElementRef;
    ...
    shiftkey(event) {

 if (this.txt.nativeElement.value.toUpperCase() === 
 this.txt.nativeElement.value && this.txt.nativeElement.value.toLowerCase() 
 !== this.txt.nativeElement.value && !event.shiftKey)
   {
        console.log("test shift key");
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can listen to the shift keydown event directly, with the `(keydown.shift)` event listener.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <input (keydown.shift)="onShift()" />
  `
})
export class AppComponent  {
  onShift() {
    console.log('shift pressed!');
  }
}
```

[Live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1hzkcf)

Answer (score 0):

Try the bellow one in your **shiftkey** method

```
shiftkey(event) {
  if(event.shiftKey) {
    console.log("test shift key");
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$event` that you're passing from your template to the `shiftkey` function will already have a `shirtKey` field on it. Simply check for that instead.

So you won't really need that template variable named `#myInput`

Like this:

```
shiftkey(event) {
  if (event.shiftKey) {
    console.log("test shift key");
  }
}
```

You'll have to bind this to `(keyup)="shiftkey($event)"` in your template.

So make the following changes to your template:

```
<input 
  type="text" 
  class="form-control" 
  dir="rtl" 
  (keyup)="shiftkey($event)"
  (keydown)="shiftkey($event)">
```

You'll then get the log once you type anything by pressing the shift key.

You can also use `(keydown)="shiftkey($event)"` if you want to check whether just the `shift` key was pressed.

Here's a [**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-shift-key-input?file=src/app/app.component.html) for your ref.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: yes man it's worked just once. I mean if i want to click shift+A multiple time it does't work

Comment: What do you mean multple time? Each time you press shift+A, it will get called. So you'll have to decide whether to use `keydown` or `keyup` as the event you're listening to.

Comment: this what i am looking for at the end : i am trying to detect that capslock is detected and if shift is not .. 
this.txt.nativeElement.value.toUpperCase() === this.txt.nativeElement.value && this.txt.nativeElement.value.toLowerCase() !== this.txt.nativeElement.value && !event.shiftKey

Comment: recheck the question please

Comment: I think you should be asking a different question for that. Asking a specific question and then pivoting from there to another doesn't really help. I'm looking into it though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181758/discussion-between-siddajmera-and-james-fallon).

Answer (score 0):

Use [Angular Pseudo-Events](https://medium.com/claritydesignsystem/angular-pseudo-events-d4e7f89247ee)

```
<input (keyup.enter)='...responds to enter...' />
<input (keydown.esc)='...responds to escape...' />
<input (keyup.shift.f)='...responds to shift+f...' />
```

**[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-shift-key-input-z9x2uc?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)**

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the host listener in your component.

```
@HostListener('keydown', ['$event']) onKeyDown(e) {
    if (e.shiftKey ) {
      console.log('shift key pressed.');
    }
  }
}
```